# How to load + unload ASPNET runtime, without using bin directory, for automated testing purposes

Tags: asp.net, testing, appdomain

I want to load the ASPNET runtime, run one or more pages, then unload it.  This is for testing purposes.  It's not UI testing; I'm really just testing the use of a library in an ASPNET context.

Normally this kind of thing is done with a call to `System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationHost.CreateApplicationHost` .

This is how I have it currently:

```
public class Manager : System.MarshalByRefObject
{
    private void HostedDomainHasBeenUnloaded(object source, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        aspNetHostIsUnloaded.Set();
    }

    private ManualResetEvent aspNetHostIsUnloaded;


    public void Run(string[] pages)
    {
        bool cleanBin = false;
        MyAspNetHost host = null;

        try
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists("bin"))
            {
                cleanBin = true;
                Directory.CreateDirectory("bin");
            }

            var a = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            string destfile= Path.Combine("bin", Path.GetFileName(a.Location));
            File.Copy(a.Location, destfile, true);

            host = 
                (MyAspNetHost) System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationHost.CreateApplicationHost
                ( typeof(MyAspNetHost), 
                  "/foo",   // virtual dir
                  System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() // physical dir
                  );

            aspNetHostIsUnloaded = new ManualResetEvent(false);

            host.GetAppDomain().DomainUnload += this.HostedDomainHasBeenUnloaded;

            foreach (string page in pages)
                host.ProcessRequest(page);

        }
        finally
        {
            // tell the host to unload
            if (host!= null)
            {
                AppDomain.Unload(host.GetAppDomain());

                // wait for it to unload
                aspNetHostIsUnloaded.WaitOne();

                // remove the bin directory
                if (cleanBin)
                {
                    Directory.Delete("bin", true);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This is the custom ASP.NET host:

```
public class MyAspNetHost : System.MarshalByRefObject 
{

    public void ProcessRequest(string page)
    {
        var request = new System.Web.Hosting.SimpleWorkerRequest(page,               // page being requested
                                                                 null,               // query
                                                                 System.Console.Out  // output
                                                                 );
        System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequest(request);
    }


    public AppDomain GetAppDomain()
    {
        return System.Threading.Thread.GetDomain();
    }    
}
```

This works ok.  But I'd like to avoid the creation of the bin directory, and the copying of the assembly into it, if possibble.

Is it possible to use `CreateApplicationHost`, and tell ASPNET to load assemblies from the current directory, or an arbitrary directory, rather than `bin`?

**EDIT** :: simplified the code a bit.
**EDIT2** :: I looked at womp's answer but it seems like doing a lot of work to avoid a little.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great question.  I remember having to deal with a similar issue a couple years ago (I wanted to have an applicationhost use a custom config file) and bookmarked [this blog post](http://www.felicepollano.com/post/Customizing-private-path-and-config-file-with-CreateApplicationHost.aspx) which I used to get me started.

It's probably way overkill for what you actually want, but perhaps it can point you in the right direction.

Comment: Wow, new process, environment variables, GAC... It sounds like a ton of work to avoid me creating and removing a directory.  It's the right idea though... I'll have to see if I can simplify it.

Answer (score 0):

Another option that I found out was to create a dummy web.config that added the bin folder as the probing folder. I tried this under .NET2. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12169675/793493